Quarto and Github Actions error: The specified path (.) is not a website
Edit: The problem had nothing to do with the GitHub token but was related to defining the path where the .qmd file is stored. See last answer
I made a Quarto website that automatically updates every day using Github actions. So far, it went well, but then I got a notification that the GitHub Token expired. Afterwards, I get this error when running the Render and Publish step:
The specified path (.) is not a website, manuscript or book project so it cannot be published.

The error occurs after running this part of the script provided by Quarto:
git config --global user.email "quarto-github-actions-publish@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Quarto GHA Workflow Runner"
  TARGET=""
  if [ "$TARGET" == "" ]; then
    TARGET="gh-pages"
  fi
  if [ "true" != "true" ]; then
    quarto publish $TARGET . --no-render --no-browser
  else
    quarto publish $TARGET . --no-browser
  fi

The error seems to refer to another problem than the token but the error occurred the same day the token expired. How is it possible to update the token? Do I need to create a token and store it in the repository manually? When setting it up, I think that this was done automatically.
Here is the full update.yaml (Changed the chron part to execu
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/20 * * * *'

jobs:
  update-report:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      pages: write
    steps:
      - name: Set up R
        uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2

      - name: Install packages
        uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
        with:
          packages: |
            any::tidyverse 
            any::janitor 

      - name: Set up Quarto
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/setup@v2

      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        
      - name: Render and Publish
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/publish@v2
        with:
          target: gh-pages
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}


I finally found the issue. The first error update-report No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/r only occurs if I use runs-on: macos-latest and does not cause the code execution to stop. I found out about this by using runs-on: ubuntu-latest as in your example.
The actual problem was that I need to specify the name of my .qmd file under "Render and Publish":
with:
   target: gh-pages
   path: filename.qmd

No idea why it has been working for the last three months and stopped now but happy to found the solution.

It sounds like you may have manually created GITHUB_TOKEN secret in your repo. This is the only explanation of the token expiry. You do not need to do this.
GitHub Actions provisions a short lived token for each job run. This secret reference
${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

refers to this short lived token which is valid for the duration of the job.

I checked in the repository and there is no secret or other variable stored (at least in repository settings/secrets and variables/. So maybe it was just a coincidence that the error occurred at the same time. Do you have an idea what the error might mean? For others, it was if the update.yaml was not in the default project folder so they needed to provide the path to it but for me, it's in the default folder

This simple workflow could be used to troubleshoot your setup:
name: Deploy Quarto Site to GitHub Pages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main  # Change this to your default branch

jobs:
  build-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      pages: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Quarto
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/setup@v2

      - name: Render Quarto site
        run: quarto render

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        uses: quarto-dev/quarto-actions/publish@v2
        with:
          target: gh-pages
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

It generates GitHub Pages site from this simple _quarto.yml
project:
  type: website
website:
  title: "My Quarto Site"
  description: "A site created with Quarto"
  page-footer: Powered by Quarto
format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
    toc: true


I reread what you said about token expiry. You must have created a PAT token some time in the past and then received an email that it expired. Is that what happened? You can check your tokens in your Developer Settings. It does not look like you are using this token in your workflow. This is just a coincidence.

I deleted the comments and used them in the answer below to be able to use nicer formating. In the Developer Settings, I only see the token I use in RStudio.

See updated answer - I was able to successfully publish with quarto actions

See my new answer thanks a lot for your help! I could solve it.
